# How to render a field strength in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, gradient, opacity

My app requires to render a field strength, i.e. the value of a function f(x,y) in a rectangle view.
I know that I can render linear or radial gradients, see [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-render-a-gradient), but I did not find a way to set the brightness or opacity of a pixel of a View depending on a function f(x,y).
I could probably assemble the View of very many subviews where the brightness or opacity of each subview is set according to such a function, but this is ugly and there should be a better way.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Use a UIImage you can change pixels there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative answer using a Metal shader. You'd need to create a shader for each implementation of the field strength algorithm, here's my attempt at your border field:

```cpp
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

[[ stitchable ]] half4 borderField(float2 position, half4 currentColor, float2 size, half4 newColor) {
    assert(size.x >= 0 && position.x <= size.x);
    assert(size.y >= 0 && position.y <= size.y);

    // Compute distance to border
    float dt = size.y - position.y;  // Distance to top
    float db = position.y;     // Distance to bottom
    float dl = position.x;      // Distance to left
    float dr = size.x - position.x;  // Distance to right
    float minDistance = min(min(dt, db), min(dl, dr));
    float r = minDistance + 1.0;
    float strength = 1.0 / sqrt(r);
    return half4(newColor.rgb, strength);

}
```

Add this to your project in a new `.metal` file.

The first two parameters are passed by default, which is the position of the current pixel and its current colour. The subsequent ones are up to you.

To use in SwiftUI, use the `.colorEffect` modifier:

```swift
Rectangle()
    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
    .colorEffect(ShaderLibrary.borderField(.float2(300, 300), .color(.blue)))
```

Note that we're passing in the size and the base color here.

This gives:

[image]

I'd be fascinated to know the performance differences you encounter between these implementations.

——

Update from Reinhard Männer where it seems Metal really is quite a lot faster!

Your 1st solution was already great, but this one is **absolutely great**!
I implemented it in my app.
I am not sure how to time it right, but I did the following:

```
var body: some View {
    let start = Date.now
    Rectangle()
        .frame(width: boardSize.width, height: boardSize.height)
        .colorEffect(ShaderLibrary.borderField(.float2(boardSize.width, boardSize.height), .color(.green)))
    let _ = print(-start.timeIntervalSinceNow)
}
```

where `boardSize` has been set the same as in my previous timing (900,357).
Earlier, the rendering took about 0.15 sec. With your metal solution and my timing above, the result is
3.0040740966796875e-05
If my timing is right, this is an unbelievable speedup of 5.000.  And this motivates me, to look also into metal. Thanks a lot!

Comment: By now I realized that the Canvas and Metal versions yield different rendering results, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77547589/1987726). Maybe you have time to look into the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, based on the suggestion of [lorem ipsum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12738750/lorem-ipsum) above.
This suggestion requires to compute an `Image` and to overlay it over a `View`.

I thus wrote the following extension to `Image`:

```
extension Image {
    
    /// Creates an Image of a given size with a given color. 
    /// The color, without the alpha value, is here hard coded, but could of course be given by a parameter.
    /// The alpha value represents the field function, depending on the (x,y) pixel value.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - size: The size of the resulting image
    ///   - alpha: The field function
    init?(size: CGSize, alpha: (_ x: Int, _ y: Int) -> Double) {
        // Set color components as 8 bits in hex. Alpha will be taken from the function parameter.
        // Pixel values are 32 bits: ARGB
        let r: UInt32 = 0x00 << 16
        let g: UInt32 = 0x00 << 8
        let b: UInt32 = 0xFF 
        
        let pixelWidth  = Int(size.width)
        let pixelHeight = Int(size.height)
        var srgbArray: [UInt32] = [] // The pixel array

        // Compute field values
        for y in 0 ..< pixelHeight {
            for x in 0 ..< pixelWidth {
                let fieldStrength = alpha(x, y)
                if fieldStrength < 0 || fieldStrength > 1.0 {
                    return nil // The alpha function did return an illegal value (< 0 or > 1).
                }
                let a = UInt32(fieldStrength * 255.0) << 24 // alpha
                srgbArray.append(a | r | g | b)
            }
        }
        
        // https://forums.swift.org/t/creating-a-cgimage-from-color-array/18634
        let cgImg = srgbArray.withUnsafeMutableBytes { ptr -> CGImage in
            let ctx = CGContext(
                data: ptr.baseAddress,
                width: pixelWidth,
                height: pixelHeight,
                bitsPerComponent: 8,
                bytesPerRow: 4 * pixelWidth,
                space: CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!,
                bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue + CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue
            )!
            return ctx.makeImage()!
        }
        
        self.init(
            cgImg,
            scale: 1.0,
            orientation: .up,
            label: Text("Field")
        )
    }
}
```

The `Image` is initialized as

```
let image = Image(size: fieldSize, alpha: alpha(x:y:))
```

where function `alpha` can be any function. Here, for demo purposes, I am using the following function:

```
func alpha(x: Int, y: Int) -> Double {
    Field.borderfield(size: fieldSize, x: x, y: y)
}
```

with

```
struct Field {
    
    static func borderfield(size: CGSize, x: Int, y: Int) -> Double {
        let a = Int(size.width)
        let b = Int(size.height)
        assert(x >= 0 && x <= a)
        assert(y >= 0 && y <= b)
        
        // Compute distance to border
        let dt = b - y  // Distance to top
        let db = y      // Distance to bottom
        let dl = x      // Distance to left
        let dr = a - x  // Distance to right
        let minDistance = min(dt, db, dl, dr)
        
        let d = Double(minDistance)
        let r = d + 1.0 // min r is now 1
        let signalStrength = 1.0/sqrt(r)
        print(signalStrength)
        return signalStrength
    }
    
}
```

Function `borderfield` is a very rough approximation to the field that a charged border of the displayed rectangle would produce.
This is the image:
[image]

Comment: I'd be inclined to look into `Canvas` for doing this, to avoid a lot of the ugly casting and pointer stuff

Comment: @jrturton I don't have experience in computer graphics, and assembled my solution by collecting suggestions from the web. Maybe you can suggest an idea how to do this with `Canvas`? I would be happy to have a more SwiftUI like solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar (but much shorter!) implementation using `Canvas`. I haven't looked at the performance but my experience with canvas is that it's extremely good, especially if you cache the resolved shading values as I have.

```swift
struct FieldStrengthView: View {

    let color: Color
    let alpha: (_ x: Int, _ y: Int) -> Double

    var body: some View {
        Canvas { context, size in
            let pixelWidth  = Int(size.width)
            let pixelHeight = Int(size.height)
            var shadings = [Double: GraphicsContext.Shading]()
            for y in 0 ..< pixelHeight {
                for x in 0 ..< pixelWidth {
                    let strength = alpha(x, y)
                    let path = Path(CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 1, height: 1))
                    if let shading = shadings[strength] {
                        context.fill(path, with: shading)
                    } else {
                        let shading = GraphicsContext.Shading.color(color.opacity(strength))
                        shadings[strength] = shading
                        context.fill(path, with: shading)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It fills in one pixel at a time using the field strength from your existing function:

```swift
#Preview {
    VStack {
        FieldStrengthView(color: .blue, alpha: { x, y in
            Field.borderfield(size: CGSize(width: 300, height: 300), x: x, y: y)
        })
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        FieldStrengthView(color: .green, alpha: { x, y in
            Field.borderfield(size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), x: x, y: y)
        })
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    }
}
```

Gives:

[image]

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: _probably_ the overall best way to do this is to use Metal shaders, sort-of as described [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-metal-shaders-to-swiftui-views-using-layer-effects), but I don't have the knowledge to write that answer :)

Comment: I just timed your and my solution. For a rect size of 900 x 357 pixels, your solution is just 1% slower than mine. On a M1 MacBook both take about 0.15 sec.

Comment: I bet a metal shader will be an order of magnitude faster. Maybe I'll work out how to write one...