# Device orientation dependent SwiftUI Metal problem: RBLayer: unable to create texture: BGRA8Unorm

Tags: ios, swiftui, metal

My iPad app has a View that uses a Metal shader as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77515224/1987726).

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

[[ stitchable ]] half4 borderField(float2 position, half4 currentColor, float2 size, half4 newColor) {
    assert(size.x >= 0 && position.x <= size.x);
    assert(size.y >= 0 && position.y <= size.y);

    // Compute distance to border
    float dt = size.y - position.y;  // Distance to top
    float db = position.y;     // Distance to bottom
    float dl = position.x;      // Distance to left
    float dr = size.x - position.x;  // Distance to right
    float minDistance = min(min(dt, db), min(dl, dr));
    float r = minDistance + 1.0;
    float strength = 1.0 / sqrt(r);
    return half4(newColor.rgb, strength);

}
```

It is applied to my View using the following modifier:

```
.colorEffect(ShaderLibrary.fields(.floatArray(viewModel.floatArray)))
```

The app can use any device orientation.
If I launch it in portrait orientation, the View is displayed correctly:

[image]

If I turn the simulator left and launch the app in landscape orientation, the following error is logged:

```
RBLayer: unable to create texture: BGRA8Unorm, [8.196, 5.200]
```

and the View is not colored:

[image]

If I turn the simulator back to portrait mode while the app is running, the View is again colored correctly.
However, if I turn it left again while the app is running, I get once more the same error, but the View looks now differently:

[image]

I don't have experience in Metal programming, and I have no idea what is wrong.
There are 2 posts that report a similar error, but apparently they do not apply to my case: [This one](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi4z92ov-mEAxXOhP0HHUzCBXQQFnoECBIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fforums.developer.apple.com%2Fforums%2Fthread%2F723146&usg=AOvVaw2kFuzlY9TIGkDUrZbkQFst&opi=89978449), and [this one](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi4z92ov-mEAxXOhP0HHUzCBXQQFnoECA0QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fforums.developer.apple.com%2Fforums%2Ftags%2Fswift-charts%2F%3FsortBy%3Doldest&usg=AOvVaw2omr51cHoKVv8iPHIMwxB2&opi=89978449).

Any suggestions?